# C# Entity Framework in-memory database how to skip or test the scalar function in unit test

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nunit, in-memory-database

I am having the following `DbFunction` in my entity context:

```
[DbFunction("fn_Replicate")]
public static string Replicate(string padChar, int patternLength, string value) => throw new Exception;
```

SQL Server function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Replicate]
    (@ReplicateChar CHAR(1) = '0',
     @PatternLength INT,
     @FieldValue NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(10)

    SELECT @Result = REPLICATE(@ReplicateChar, @PatternLength - LEN(@FieldValue)) + @FieldValue

    RETURN @Result
END
```

And in my C# code:

```
    if (query.Any(usr => OrganisationContextNew.Replicate("0", (EmployeNumberPatternLength - usr.PersonNumber.Length), usr.PersonNumber) ==
                              OrganisationContextNew.Replicate("0", (EmployeNumberPatternLength - employeeNumber.Length), employeeNumber)
                            && usr.CompanyCode.Code.Equals(companyCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
```

I am using in-memory database and when I run the unit test, it fails with the function and throw new exception as defined in the context.

My test setup is:

```
    [SetUp]
    public virtual void Setup()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture().UseDefaultBehaviors(skipNonPrimitiveMembers: true);

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OrganisationContextNew>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Options;
        _context = new OrganisationContextNew(options);
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

It worked with the following implementation:

```
    [DbFunction("fn_Replicate")]
    public static string Replicate(char padChar, int patternLength, string value) 
    {
        var padLength = patternLength - value.Length;

        return padLength >= 0 ? value : value.PadLeft(padLength, padChar);
    }
```

Comment: Obviously, in-memory database does not have your custom function ;) Have you tried instead of throwing exception in function body, implement replication by C#?

Comment: I have thrown the exception in the function body as mentioned above.

Comment: May i know how to implement replication by C# instead of throwing exception in function body?

Comment: something like this:
        [DbFunction("fn_Replicate")]
        public static string Replicate(string padChar, int patternLength, string value) 
        {
            var padLength = patternLength - value.Length;
            char pad = '0';

            return value.PadLeft(padLength, pad);
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DbFunction("fn_Replicate")]
    public static string Replicate(char padChar, int patternLength, string value) 
    {
        var padLength = patternLength - value.Length;

        return padLength >= 0 ? value : value.PadLeft(padLength, padChar);
    }
```